# How to dynamically set a imageView from a file?

Tags: android, imageview

I need to set a imageView dynamically. The image is at drawable. This code is ok:

```
Bitmap bm2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image1); 
img_pergunta.setImageBitmap(bm2);
```

The problem is that I need to start from string, but this code doesn´t work:

```
File imgFile = new  File("/drawable/image1.png");
Bitmap bm2 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
img_pergunta.setImageBitmap(bm2);
```

How do I solve it?

Comment: BitmapFactory.decodeFile(.. path to file.. ); is ok. But the used path is not possible. Also the paths used in both answers are nonsense.

Comment: I tested String str2 = this.getClass().getPackage().getName(); and recovered str2 = com.cursoandroid.autenticacaousuario.autenticacaousuario

Comment: the path is still incorrect, I tried this.getClass().getPackage().getName() just to be sure the correct name of package

Comment: Why would a package name be a path?

Comment: `problem is that I need to start from string` Why? Tell the vakue of the string  And are you still trying to get a file in drawable using yhe File class? That will not go.

Comment: The idea is to save some images at drawable like image1, image2, image3 ... image30 and the I can dinamically build this name of file image. When the user select 15 I build image15 and pick the image from the name of file. I could also construt a switch case like: case 15: pick image15, but I would like a more compact code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the id (which you use in decodeResource()) using context.getResources().getIdentifier() and a name like image4.

Comment: int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("q8circ1");  // doesn't work

Comment: Correct. I see you did not google for declaration or example.

Comment: I tried: int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("image1","image",getPackageName());
        Bitmap bm2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resId);
        img_pergunta.setImageBitmap(bm2);

Comment: int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("image1","drawable",getPackageName());

Answer (score 0):

You probably have given a bad path to the file, try

`File imgFile = new  File("android.resource://COM.EXAMPLE.PACKAGE/drawable/image1.png");`

but replace the package name with correct one - yours

Comment: E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /android.resource:/com.cursoandroid.autenticacaousuario.autenticacaousuario/drawable/q8circ1.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Answer (score 0):

You can create new file by giving path as mentioned below,

```java
File file = new File("android.resource://"+R.class.getPackage().getName()+"/" +resourceId);
```

resourceId can be replaced by `R.drawable.resourceName`

Comment: E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /android.resource:/com.cursoandroid.autenticacaousuario.autenticacaousuario/2131099768: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: I tested String str2 = this.getClass().getPackage().getName(); and recovered str2 = com.cursoandroid.autenticacaousuario.autenticacaousuario